# Loading JSON in PHP53: ZVAL_DELREF in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, centos5, json

I'm trying to loading JSON into the new-installed PHP5.3.1 on a CentOS server. Previously there was a PHP5.1 or near and due to the latest version of WordPress I had to upgrade the PHP.

I tried to install JSON via **yum** with:

```
    yum install php-pecl-json
```

But I get a "php53-common is in conflict with php-common". With **--skip-broken** doesn't work, either.

I've tried it manually and got the JSON package via PEAR:

```
 pear install pecl/json
```

After some errors regarding certain functions that are decrapted in this new version of PHP, 
I still got the following error on **php -v**:

```
 # php -v
 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/json.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/json.so: undefined symbol: ZVAL_DELREF in Unknown on line 0
 PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Mar 30 2011 13:51:54)
```

Afterwards, I've installed JSON manually, entered the folder and did **phpize** prior to **./configure, make and make install**. I also copied the json.so to /usr/lib64/php/modules. Nothing working so far.

The **json.ini** in /etc/php.d states:

```
extension = json.so
```

I did replace json.so from "extension = " with /usr/lib64/php/modules/json.so. And also entered "/usr/lib64/php/modules" as **extension_dir** into /etc/php.ini.

No luck. Can anyone help?

Thank you.

UPDATE:

```
 # yum repolist
 Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
 Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
  * base: centos.mirror.lstn.net
  * epel: fedora-epel.mirror.lstn.net
  * extras: centos-distro.cavecreek.net
  * rpmforge: fr2.rpmfind.net
  * updates: mirrors.serveraxis.net
 base                                                     | 2.1 kB     00:00     
 epel                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00     
 extras                                                   | 2.1 kB     00:00     
 rpmforge                                                 | 1.1 kB     00:00     
 updates                                                  | 1.9 kB     00:00     
 repo id      repo name                                           status
 base         CentOS-5 - Base                                     enabled:  3,535
 epel         Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - x86_64      enabled:  6,543
 extras       CentOS-5 - Extras                                   enabled:    299
 rpmforge     RHEL 5 - RPMforge.net - dag                         enabled: 10,691
 updates      CentOS-5 - Updates                                  enabled:    765
 repolist: 21,833
```

UPDATE 2: JSON is already packed within php-common, so when installing PHP from REMI repo, for example, version 5.3.6 you'll already have JSON installed.

It seems that after that, trying to install JSON via *pecl install json* or manually will output the error I've stated above.

Thank you.

Comment: "undefined symbol: ZVAL_DELREF" isan indication that the .so file was compiled in a wrong way. (ZVAL_DELREF is a C preprocessor macro an should not appear in the binary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I get a "php53-common is in conflict with php-common". With
>   --skip-broken doesn't work, either.

Please give us the output of `yum repolist`?

"No luck" means still got the same error when installing via `pear`?

> Afterwards, I've installed JSON manually, entered the folder and did
>   phpize prior to ./configure, make and make install. I also copied the
>   json.so to /usr/lib64/php/modules

`make install` will copy the extension to `/usr/lib64/php/modules` automatically, no need to manual copy.

Also take a look at created time to make sure that you loaded the right extension. Don't forget to reload (restart) Apache after that.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your help. I've updated my post with _yum repolist_. As to the created time, I'm not sure how to see that, but I did this: **ls -l json.so**: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 96637 Aug 3 02:03 json.so.

Comment: Can you talk more details: what's the root cause and how do you fix?

Comment: I've updated my post for everyone to know. I'm still not sure why I had that specific error on _php -v_, but if you install PHP 5.3.6 you will already have JSON installed with *php-common* (5.3.6, too). I guess I've overwritten that automatically installation with a manual installation of json and it basically lead to errors.

Comment: How do you install `5.3.6`? When I do `yum install php53` I get `5.3.3`.